# Flask: How to show data from database

Tags: python, flask

I use Flask and Firebase for database.

I want to show 7 variables from database and i made it but not the way i wanted it.

When i get data from database , my screen looks like this :

[image]

I am trying to shown like this:
[image]
Without ' { } '
Heres my code:
This is routes.py

```
@app.route('/satis', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def satis():
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        sehir=request.form['il']
        yas=request.form['yas']
        id=request.form['id']
        kat=request.form['kategori']
        gun=request.form['satisgunu']
        cins=request.form['cinsiyet']
        tarz=request.form['satistarzi']
        db = firebase.database()
        db.child("names").push({"sehir": sehir,"yas":yas,"id":id,"kat":kat,"gun":gun,"cins":cins,"tarz":tarz})
        todo = db.child("names").get()
        to = todo.val()
        return render_template('satis.html', t=to.values())
    return render_template('satis.html')
```

This is satis.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        {% for l in t %}
            <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item">
                    <h4>{{l}}</h4>
                </li>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you want it to look like instead? You have to write the HTML to display the data how you want.

Comment: Because landing on a page is a `GET` request and your response to _that_ doesn't send `t`? Also, `{% for l in t %}` is horrible naming for being able to maintain the code

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Without ' { ' . I editted my question